# spark streaming cannot receive data from kafka if send some message to kafka beforehand

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I produce some messages first and these messages are persisted on disk by kafka's brokers. Then I start the spark streaming program to process these data, but I can't receive anything in spark streaming. And there is not any error log.

However, If I produce message when the spark streaming program is running, it can receive data.

Can spark streaming only receive the real time data from kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the behavior of what data is consumed at the start of a new consumer stream, you should provide `auto.offset.reset` as part of the properties used to create the kafka stream.

`auto.offset.reset` can take the following values:

- earliest => the kafka topic will be consumed from the earliest offset available
- latest => the kafka topic will be consumed, starting at the current latest offset

Also note that depending on the kafka consumer model you are using (received-based or direct), the behavior of a restarted spark streaming job will be different.